# Why do carbs make you lose focus during your workout?

Tags: carbohydrate, pre-workout

Mr. Olympia competitor Ben Pakulski advises:

> Pre-workout. No carbs. Why no carbs? Neurological focus.
>   Neurotransmitter focus. I find that I get much better brain focus in
>   my training and ends up giving me better overall outcome.

Source: https://youtu.be/WPIWsQhZ9CM?t=33s

An article from Forbes also says low carbs increase vigilance at the expense of hurting other traits:

> When consuming low-carb diets in the short term, this is certainly true. In a 2008 study, psychologists placed 19 women on either a calorie restricted low-carb diet or a calorie restricted high-carb diet for 28 days. Throughout the study, participants’ memory, reaction time, and vigilance were tested at regular intervals. While those on the low-carb diet enjoyed a slight boost in vigilance, they suffered impaired reaction time and reduced visuospatial memory.

Source: http://www.forbes.com/sites/rosspomeroy/2013/11/12/do-low-carbohydrate-diets-make-you-dumber/

Neither of these sources explained why low carbs increase focus/vigilance. What is the reason?

Comment: Just to state the obvious, Pakulski uses steroids so he's operating literally with different biology. Pumped with enough test I imagine you can cut carbs back quite significantly.

Comment: Steroids help build muscle faster. Steroids have nothing to do with focus.

Comment: And, watching that video, he implies that carb consumption is a very individual thing. For him, maybe no carbs works. That doesn't mean that it applies to everyone.

Comment: @JoJo, testosterone *has* an impact on emotion, especially considering the doses a professional body builder employs is far above the safe threshold that would be prescribed for something like low-testosterone production (typically it's 2x-3x). http://press.endocrine.org/doi/abs/10.1210/jcem.75.6.1464655

Comment: @JoJo - Steroids have nothing to do with focus? Read about Halotestin and Cheque-Drops also you may heard about Roid Rage?

Comment: Voting to keep open as the question is directly related to the workout.

Comment: I have the best focus when training on an empty stomach, so no carbs nor anything at all except a coffee, somehow I feel more aggressive and more focused :-) - that may not work for others though

Comment: @Alec - Yes, the question is directly related to a workout, but it's basically personal opinion. Each person will react to carbs and/or steroids in different ways.

Comment: @JohnP - I have a hard time believing that there are no common factors between different people in this regard. Surely there are certain elements we all share.

Comment: @Alec - Yes, everyone shares certain elements, and there are some people that will react the same way. But, there is nothing that we know of that says *why*, or how to identify which person you might be, which makes any answer guesswork.

Comment: I feel like the question would be better phrased to indicate that there are potential factors that might affect focus and asking what they are, thereby bypassing a binary "they definitely affect your focus or they do not".

Comment: Just from personal perspective, since i started taking weight gainer with high carb content pre-workout i noticed i have better focus and better workouts.

Comment: @JohnP re:individual response to carbs and drugs. Not only that, but even the same lifter will react differently depending on what he/she gets used to. Train fasted early in the morning for a few months and you won't stand lifting weights with a full stomach, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

As Pulaski stated he feels better training without carbs before his workout. As a number of studies have proven that when you eat carbs, protein and fats does not significantly effect your gains. So you could just try to do what fits you best. Also as stated above Pulaski abuses steroid and thus is not comparable.

P.S. Most youtubers, suplement companies make money of of people who don't know what they're doing. Don't fall into these scams. They mostly use information from research that fits what they want to say and make a fuss about insignificant so-called 'muscle-growers'.

Keep up the good work!